# pic random images from array

Tags: php, arrays, scandir

So I have this code that randomly pics an image out of the array provided:

```
$bg = array('1.jpg', '2.jpg', '2.jpg',); // array of filenames

$i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
$selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
```

But I would like to get the images from a folder no matter the name and how many there are.

I've tried this :

```
$dir = "bg_photos/less_saturation/";

$exclude = array( ".","..");
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $files = scandir($dir);
    foreach($files as $file){
        if(!in_array($file,$exclude)){
            echo $file;         
            $bg = array($file); // array of filenames
            $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
            $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
        }
    }
}
```

But this only ever gives me the last image in the array ...
Can anyone help ?

Cheers

Chris

Comment: tip 1: **print_r** **$bg** array,
tip 2: Read and compare with array **$bg = array('1.jpg', '2.jpg', '2.jpg',);**

Comment: add 1 item to array use **$bg[] = $file**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code. This is collect all the files, exept `.` and `..`, into an array, and get a random item from the array.

```
$dir = "bg_photos/less_saturation/";
$exclude = array( ".","..");
$bg = array();
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $files = scandir($dir);
    foreach($files as $file){
        if(!in_array($file,$exclude)){
            echo $file;         
            //Use as an array
            $bg[] = $file; // array of filenames
        }
    }
}
$selectedBg = $bg[array_rand($bg)];
```

Comment: Very Cool
This last line is what I was looking for
Thank you very much
I'll accept your question in just a few minutes :)

Comment: but do it outside of your loop. And use `$bg[]` instead `$bg = ` because you will always overwrote that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$dir = "bg_photos/less_saturation/";

if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'));

    $i = rand(0, count($files)-1); // generate random number size of the array
    $selectedBg = $files[$i]; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
}
```

Comment: This is not random. It will gives you back always the last one.

Comment: @lolka_bolka why will this only return only the last one ? Am I missing something ?